# How can I call event.target.playVideo() using npm 'react-youtube' when a parent state changes without re-rendering child?

Tags: reactjs, events, youtube-api

I feel like this is a simple issue caused by my lack of experience with react, forgive me if I've over-complicated it.

Using npm 'react-youtube', I am trying to call event.target.pauseVideo() on the Video component whenever a specific parent state changes. I have a button which toggles the video component's div display to 'none' or 'block' when clicked, I want this button to also pause or play the video without having to re-render the Video component. I can call event.target.pauseVideo() inside the provided _onReady(){} or _onStateChange(){} with no issues, however I want it to be triggered when I press a button, not on either of those triggers.

I've tried creating my own method in the Video component which calls event.target.pauseVideo(), however I do not know how to trigger this from the parent (I think this is doable using refs, but everywhere I read says refs should not be used 99% of the time.) I've also tried passing event.target.pauseVideo() to the component from the parent, but this seems to try to use an event or target from the parent which doesn't exist instead of the Video component's.

Parent:

```
class Window extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      currentDisplay: 1,
      isPaused: 0,
    }
  }   

  renderVideo(isPaused){
    return <Video isPaused={isPaused}>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='window'>

        <div className = 'vid'>
          {this.renderVideo(this.state.isPaused)}
        </div>

        <div className = 'PauseButton'>
          <Pause handleClick={() => {this.togglePause()}}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}
```

togglePause() just changes the pause state from 0 to 1 and vice versa

Pause button Component:

```
class PauseButton extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={() =>  {this.props.handleClick()}  }>
        Pause
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Video Component:

```
class Video extends React.Component{
  _pause(event, isPaused){
    if(isPaused = 1){event.target.pauseVideo()}
  }

  _onReady(event) {
    //event.target.pauseVideo()
  }
  render(){ 
    const opts = {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: { // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
      autoplay: 1,
      }
    }       
    return(
      <YouTube
      videoId= {'21X5lGlDOfg'}
      opts={opts}
      onReady={this._onReady}
      onStateChange={this._onStateChange}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Currently, the '_pause()' method in the video component is never triggered, but I would like it to be triggered whenever the pause button is clicked.

The code above plays the video without issues, however I am looking for a way to trigger the _pause() method in the Video component without having to re render the component.

Answer (score 0):

Created a code sandbox with Video gettign paused when clicking pause button. Achieved using React Hooks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-cerf-0os7t